# How to incorporate jar file into docker container while building it in jenkins

Tags: java, mysql, docker, maven, jenkins

I am trying to incorporate mysql-connector-11.0.19-jar in a docker container. Currently, it is being downloaded and manually placed in lib directory of docker container and starting the jar using entrypoint command in docker file but now I am trying to build docker container through jenkins by adding dockerfile and jenkinsfile to the git repo. I tried adding mysql-connector plugin as maven dependency in pom.xml but not sure if that is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `curl` or `wget` to download the Jar and then build your Docker image. In the Dockerfile you can have a line to copy the Jar.

```
sh'''
#Download driver
curl -k https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.30/mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar --output mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar
# Bild docker image
docker build something -t
'''
```

Another option is to use docker `ADD` instead of `COPY` and directly download the Jar into the Image.

```
ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.30/mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar /tmp/main.go
```